# Symfony : The service has a dependency on a non-existent parameter

Tags: php, dependency-injection, debian, virtualbox, symfony-3.4

I'm new on Symfony, I clone the project on which I work actually. When I launch command `php bin/console debug:router` on my VM I got the following error:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAB0r.png).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems that a parameter is not defined in your environment. Did you use `env var`?

Comment: TIp: Write your question in English because not all people can read french.

Comment: I've used " env var" too but the error stay the same.

Comment: Did you miss a config `services` file where the service `ThrowableManager` is defined? Did you use a different env  ( and a file is not loaded)?

Comment: The error says: ** "The service" AppBundle \ Service \ SheetManager "has a dependency on a non-exist parameter "temp_public_directory" **  
but in the service section, I have this code:

Comment: Yes, there is a parameter named `temp_public_directory`. Did you find it in your code somewhere?

Comment: Yes... I've find it

Comment: And it's defined? In which file? Does it change from `env` like `config_dev`, or `config_prod`?

Comment: On the **services.yml**, I have this code :  `AppBundle\Service\SheetManager:
        arguments:
            $tempDirectory: '%temp_public_directory%'` </br> and errors from command  `config_dev` and `config_prod` are the same too

Comment: And this parameter is defined somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I've defined it on a class the **class SheetManager** I've declared :  `class SheetManager {  private $tempDirectory; `

Comment: I talk about `symfony` parameter. There are defined in `config` folders under the key `parameters` like [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-parameters)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Symfony 3.4 and I imported all on parameters.yml in config/config.yml like this   `imports:`   `- { resource: parameters.yml }  
    - { resource: security.yml }  
    - { resource: services.yml }`

Comment: Yes but the `temp_public_directory` is defined in this file like `temp_public_directory: -----`

Comment: So finally, what should I do? ☺

Comment: Add a key like this in a config file : 
```parameters:
    temp_public_directory: 'folder'```
In `app/config/config.yml` by default.

Comment: it has not work yet

Comment: What is the result of this command ` php bin/console deb:container --parameter temp_public_directory` ( it return the value of a specific parameter if it exists)

Comment: it returns the same error `The service "  AppBundle\Service\ShettManager" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "temp_public_directory"`

Comment: If you try to comment the service definition for `AppBundle\Service\ShettManager` then re-launch command?

Comment: Maybe you can try to copy something like that: https://pastebin.com/hRnHiJ8g

Comment: You are welcome. But it's really strange that you have to write this file if all config file commits. Maybe the other environment has some change?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe the problem comes from the fact that I made a copy of the project in question and it is on this copy that I work.

Comment: Yes but if it's a `total copy` it should work